error: node_modules\axios\index.js:D:MindInsight-main\node_mo (reading "addHelper
When I tried npm install jest, and the console showed that I had four high-risk vulnerabilities, I executed the NPM audit fix-force as he gave me the command, and I hadn't run my program yet, when I tried to run the app on my phone again, I was given the following error.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried to clear the cache while I was trying to fix the error, then re-npm install and re-run, what is the problem and how should I solve it?
